# How to delete duplicates based off a composite key without using merge

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, sql-delete

So I currently have a an issue where I am encountering duplicates based off a **composite key** when trying to insert into a table from a materialized view. The **composite key** is composed of three columns: ***TIMESTAMP, NAME and TYPE***. I've tried using the following method but I still run into the same issue (I get a duplicate error message and the stored procedure stops running). IS there a way to handle the exception so that it just skips over the duplicate row? If not I thought of the below DELETE statement to get rid of duplicates, is this the correct approach?

Below is the 'bulk insert' statement that I am using:

```
DELETE FROM table
     where timestamp IN (SELECT DISTINCT ts from mv_1)
       and person IN (SELECT distinct name from mv_1)
       and TYPE IN (SELECT distinct data_type from mv_1);
       commit;
--
 DELETE FROM table
     WHERE    timestamp || person || TYPE IN
              (SELECT DISTINCT
                         ts
                      || name
                      || data_type
                 FROM edb.mv_1); 
COMMIT;
--
INSERT INTO table
           (person
            timestamp,
            TYPE)
  SELECT name,
         ts,
         data_type
    FROM edb.mv_1 a
   WHERE  a.row_id NOT IN
                (SELECT row_id
                   FROM (SELECT v.*,
                                ROW_NUMBER ()
                                OVER (
                                   PARTITION BY v.name,
                                                v.data_type,
                                                v.ts
                                   ORDER BY row_id)
                                   AS rn
                           FROM mv_1 v) t
                  WHERE rn > 1)
```

**Note:** row_id is a column I made in MV_1 just so I would have a column that would give me a unique identifier.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the problem actually because you have composite key combinations in `mv_1` that already exist in the target table? Or because there are duplicates within `mv_1`? Using `distinct` in your second delete kind of suggests the latter. (Also `distinct` with `in()` is a bit pointless). And if you do have duplicate keys, how are you deciding which to keep? (Also, to actually address your question about skipping the row: yes; [DML error logging](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423__BGBEIACB).)

Comment: Thanks for your response @AlexPoole. I want to insert / keep the latest value. The composite key exists in the target table but not the materialized view (MV_1). There are two scenarios where duplicates can occur 1) Duplicates actually in MV_1 2) A record already existing for that particular composite key (if that makes sense).

Answer (score 0):

I'd make the table safe by adding a composite primary key (which you sure have done already):

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD CONSTRAINT pk_table PRIMARY KEY (timestamp, person, type);
```

Furthermore, I'd make the materialized view safe by adding a primary key there, too. Depending on how the mv ist built, you need to change the query that is feeding it, so that no duplicates occur. See for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46295406/oracle-materialized-views-with-primary-key).

If both are safe, the insert is simple:

```
INSERT INTO table (timestamp, person, type, further_col1, col2, ...)
SELECT timestamp, name, type, further_col1, col2, ....
  FROM edb.mv_1 m
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT * 
         FROM table t2 
        WHERE t2.timestamp = m.timestamp
          AND t2.person    = m.name
          AND t2.type      = m.type
       );
```

If you have only the three columns, you can shorten the insert to:

```
INSERT INTO table (timestamp, person, type)
SELECT timestamp, name  , type FROM edb.mv_1  
MINUS
SELECT timestamp, person, type FROM table;
```

Please make sure the thee columns are NOT NULL in table and mv. And please don't name tables `table` and columns `timestamp` or `type`. I am sure they are only examples.